# How to lock the modifier key reliably using Sticky-Keys under Windows-10

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio-code, microsoft-edge, accessibility, sticky-keys

I am having trouble with my hands, so I am trying Sticky-Keys to make typing easier. I have enabled "Lock the modifier key when pressed twice in a row", but is is not reliable, and there is no feedback to indicate that the modifier key has locked.

Can anyone suggest why locking modifiers will not work for me? Is a certain time lag required? Can I be pressing the modifier two times too quickly or too slowly? Does sticky-keys not work reliably with all software?

I am using the edge browser and vscode under windows 10 for my experiments, and all are updated to the latest releases, as far as I know

Comment: Pure guess, it's connected to double-click speed. Try lengthening that.

Comment: I wish there was some feedback status indication so I can see when the double modifier press works. OSX is much better in this area!

Answer (score 2):

What I have leant:

```
- a single press control, alt or windows modifier key modifies the next non-modifier key
- the control, alt and windows keys 'lock' if you press twice
- a third press clears the modifier
- multiple modifiers work together
```

Shift is slightly different:

```
- either shift alone shifts the next non modifier key
- a right then left shift key presses 'locks' shift.  
- pressing the left shift cancels the shift 'lock'
- pressing the right shift also cancels, but the next key is shifted
```

I understood the operation of sticky-keys by watching the sticky-keys icon on the task bar. (I missed it at first because I usually hide my task bar).